# install couchbase php extension on xampp under windows 10

Tags: php, xampp, couchbase

i've tried many times to install couchbase client using this tutorial : http://trondn.blogspot.ro/2013/04/couchbase-php-xampp-and-windows.html ,, but is not working,,

**when i run composer update i get the following errors**

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_couchbase.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_couchbase.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - ytake/laravel-couchbase 0.5.7 requires ext-couchbase ^2.2.2 -> the requested PHP extension couchbase is missing from your system.
    - ytake/laravel-couchbase 0.5.6 requires ext-couchbase >=2.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension couchbase is missing from your system.
    - ytake/laravel-couchbase 0.5.5 requires ext-couchbase >=2.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension couchbase is missing from your system.
    - ytake/laravel-couchbase 0.5.3 requires ext-couchbase >=2.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension couchbase is missing from your system.
    - ytake/laravel-couchbase 0.5.2 requires ext-couchbase >=2.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension couchbase is missing from your system.
    - ytake/laravel-couchbase 0.5.1 requires ext-couchbase >=2.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension couchbase is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for ytake/laravel-couchbase ^0.5 -> satisfiable by ytake/laravel-couchbase[0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 0.5.5, 0.5.6, 0.5.7].
```

what should i do? please i need help

Comment: Perhaps try following a newer tutorial if you can find one?

Comment: i've tried another tutorials but with no result

Comment: How about the official documentation? https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/php/start-using-sdk.html

Comment: i've tried also with the official documentation and no result,, the errors are all the time the same

Comment: Can you show a directory listing of `C:\xampp\php\ext\ ` that shows that file is available?

Answer (score 0):

Official PHP SDK binaries for Windows published on
https://developer.couchbase.com/server/other-products/release-notes-archives/php-sdk

Make sure you put `php_couchbase.dll` into your extensions directory, and `libcouchbase.dll` into your SAPI PATH (or process current directory).

Comment: SAPI PATH? in what sense?

Comment: When you SAPI tries to load extension, the dynamic linker will see that `php_couchbase.dll` depends on `libcouchbase.dll`. And this would be the next library it will try to load, but because we cannot specify that path to libcouchbase, it should be available in PATH or current directory of the SAPI (i.e. if you use CLI, it should be in `php.exe` directory).

Comment: That path doesn't exist anymore